# Can you see managed services definitions and assignments in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-resource-manager, azureportal

I have a setup which uses Azure AD B2C and I want to enable monitoring using Azure Monitor.

I followed the steps described on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/azure-monitor

It works, but before I enroll it to other environments I would like to verify what changes the [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/azure-monitor#33-create-an-azure-resource-manager-template) being referred to in the documentation exactly made. If I interpret the ARM template correctly it creates a Managed Services Registration Definition and assigns this to provided resource group.

Is it possible to see in the Azure Portal what Managed Services Registration Definitions are assigned to a resource group?

ARM Template:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "mspOfferName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Specify a unique name for your offer"
        },
        "defaultValue": "<to be filled out by MSP> Specify a title for your offer"
    },
    "mspOfferDescription": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the Managed Service Provider offering"
        },
        "defaultValue": "<to be filled out by MSP> Provide a brief description of your offer"
    },
    "managedByTenantId": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Specify the tenant id of the Managed Service Provider"
        },
        "defaultValue": "<to be filled out by MSP> Provide your tenant id"
    },
    "authorizations": {
        "type": "array",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Specify an array of objects, containing tuples of Azure Active Directory principalId, a Azure roleDefinitionId, and an optional principalIdDisplayName. The roleDefinition specified is granted to the principalId in the provider's Active Directory and the principalIdDisplayName is visible to customers."
        },
        "defaultValue": [
            { 
                "principalId": "<Replace with group's OBJECT ID>",
                "principalIdDisplayName": "Azure AD B2C tenant administrators",
                "roleDefinitionId": "b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
            }
        ]
    },
    "rgName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "<Replace with Resource Group's Name e.g. az-monitor-rg>"
    }              
},
"variables": {
    "mspRegistrationName": "[guid(parameters('mspOfferName'))]",
    "mspAssignmentName": "[guid(parameters('mspOfferName'))]"
},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationDefinitions",
        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
        "name": "[variables('mspRegistrationName')]",
        "properties": {
            "registrationDefinitionName": "[parameters('mspOfferName')]",
            "description": "[parameters('mspOfferDescription')]",
            "managedByTenantId": "[parameters('managedByTenantId')]",
            "authorizations": "[parameters('authorizations')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
        "name": "rgAssignment",
        "resourceGroup": "[parameters('rgName')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationDefinitions/', variables('mspRegistrationName'))]"
        ],
        "properties":{
            "mode":"Incremental",
            "template":{
                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "parameters": {},
                "resources": [
                    {
                        "type": "Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationAssignments",
                        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
                        "name": "[variables('mspAssignmentName')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "registrationDefinitionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationDefinitions/', variables('mspRegistrationName'))]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {
    "mspOfferName": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[concat('Managed by', ' ', parameters('mspOfferName'))]"
    },
    "authorizations": {
        "type": "array",
        "value": "[parameters('authorizations')]"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, Msp offer and Msp description refers to the ARM template publication. Whenever you want to create your own managed service in the ARM template you assign one Msp offer for your service and description and send it to customers for use or even upload the template in Azure marketplace.

MSP is managed service offering, Where Microsoft cloud partners create their own managed service and make it available to their customer’s tenant privately for specific users or publish it publicly in Azure Marketplace to get more customers using their Service.

Imagine a scenario, where you are a MS partner managing multiple customers and their tenants, You require to create a managed service for your customer and provide them delegated access to your service, Here you first create an ARM template to onboard your customers, you can do it via Azure Lighthouse too. For onboarding you keep, Msp offer ID which is unique for individual customers also if you want to keep the offer ID default for all customers, Even that can be set, After Msp offer ID, you can delegate your service to the customer by either allowing them to assign their tenant Id or service principal, group, user object ID in your template, Once that is assigned your managed service will be available for the customers to use. You can keep the offer public or private, you can also keep one managed identity for all the customers or allow customers to provide their own Object ID of their tenant’s group, users or service principals.

In the above document, ARM template is created with MSP offer in your Azure AD tenant to provide delegated access to your Azure AD B2C tenant, Thus you are managing your Azure AD B2C tenant via your Azure AD by providing resource group as a delegated resource between both the tenant and also your Group object ID which acts as a authorization between your Azure AD and Azure AD B2C tenant. If you go by above scenario- Imagine your Azure AD tenant as a partner tenant trying to provide managed service to your Azure AD B2C tenant.

I have followed the document and deployed an Azure monitoring service for Azure AD B2C

This ARM template is asking to connect the resource group from our or Azure subscription to our Azure AD B2C tenant.

[image]

It is authorizing our Azure AD B2C tenant with the group’s Object ID projecting it with Resource group of our Azure subscription.

mspOfferName- is the name of the offer or service that is being provided by our Azure subscription. Here we can give any name according to our need. For now we are integrating Azure monitor log analytics workspace with our Azure AD B2C tenant, Thus we use name – Azure AD B2C Monitoring.

mspofferDescription- Description of your service

managedByTenantID- this is going to be the Tenant ID or managed ID of your Azure AD B2C to onboard it to our subscription resource.

roleDefinitionID- is populated automatically, Which is your azure role, In my case I am using Azure subscription with Owner role, Thus the role definition Id of owner role is populated.

rgName- Is the name of our Resource group where our log analytics workspace is deployed.

[image]

[image]

After I created the Managed service- I went to go to resource and the deployment was successful.

[image]

After the deployment, I got the audit logs from azure ad b2c to my Azure log analytics successfully.

Customer statement:- “Is it possible to see in the Azure Portal what Managed Services Registration Definitions are assigned to a resource group?”

To view what managed service is deployed, you can visit > Azure Portal > Search> Service Provider >

**You will find your service provider msp like below:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

As, this managed service is not part of Azure marketplace the Marketplace offer is not visible.

**You can view your resource group delegated to the azure ad b2c tenant here:-**

[image]

**You can also visit your Resource group and check the deployment history:-**

[image]

Here, Are the deployments that were succeeded as part of managed service: -

[image]

You can also view the complete logs of these 3 deployments that were created for your managed service creation and monitoring by visiting Activity Log :-

[image]